# Insert command for asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql

I insert picture paths into database and when I get the path I display them with `img` tag.

I can do it but I couldn't find the methods that I have to write after sql query.

What I have to write after sql query?

In `Page_Load` my select command works.

```
 c = new Common(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ahapp"]);
    string sql = "select Query";
    string str = "";
    DataTable dt = c.GetDataTable(sql);
    foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
    {
        str += "<img src='" + item["path"].ToString() + "' style='width:100px' />";
    }

    dokList.InnerHtml = str;
```

This code always says:
[image]

```
 sql ="INSERT INTO DR_OZLUK VALUES(3," + ddlDoktor.SelectedValue + "," + belgeid + ",3," + str + ",1)";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, c);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone. I found the solution. I add this code `c.GetExecuteNonQuery(sql);` and made c global.

Answer (score 2):

Your `c` object seems to be something else other than SqlConnection type. What is that Common class? The `SqlCommand` takes two parameters. The first one is string which is either an sql statement or the name of a stored procedure, and the other argument is an object of type SqlConnection.

Answer (score 2):

The *insert statement* is vulnerable with sql injection but the problem has nothing to do with the sql statement. The problem is you are passing `Common` class instead of `Connection` object in `SqlCommand` Objection.

Try this code snippet:

```
string connStr = "connection string here";
string sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO DR_OZLUK VALUES (3, @val1, @val2, 3, @val3, 1)";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
{
    using(SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand())
    {
        comm.Connection = conn;
        comm.CommandText = sqlStatement;
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", ddlDoktor.SelectedValue);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val2", belgeid);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val3", str);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch(SqlException e)
        {
            // do something with the exception
            // do not hide it
            // e.Message.ToString()
        }
    }
}
```

For proper coding

- use `using` statement for propr object disposal
- use `try-catch` block to properly handle objects

Answer (score 0):

I think c should be connection object

```
c = new Common
```

you are passing c inplace of connection object.

Signature of the SQLCommand to create object is

```
public SqlCommand(
    string cmdText,
    SqlConnection connection
)
```

so according to it your second argument must be connection object. That is the reason its giving you an error. you are passing Common class object to create command object. visi MSDN link to get more : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/877h0y3a.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Either your c is not a `SqlConnection` or your IDE has another error that is confusing with the error you have pasted. Sometimes VS2010 gets broken when showing errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Or try this, this sample code is very secure and 100% works any time, you can copy paste it but u must put your connection string and table 

    string connectionStr = "connection string STRING";
    string sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO yourtable VALUES (ID, @pam1, @pam2)";
    ///// Go to Base and execute Query but with trycatch because if you have problem with using connection it will tell you

    try{

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        using(SqlCommand komand = new SqlCommand(conn,sqlQuery)) //command to use connection and Sqlquery

    string fromcontrol = "test"; //this is string just for test

            komand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pam1", fromcontrol.ToString());
            komand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val2", fromcontrol.ToString());

                conn.Open();
                komand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch(SqlException e)
            {
    //throw your execption to javascript  or response; e.Message.ToString() + "SQL connection or query error"; 
            }

    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    //throw your execption to javascript  or response; e.Message.ToString()+ "system error"; 
    }

finally
{
conn.Close();
conn.Dispose();
}

        }
    }
```